# iOS : Objective C : How do I detect my UIWebView is loading a URL which needs to be open in new tab?

Tags: objective-c, ios11

I just wanted to implement a feature like safari for new tab. I don't worry about session right now. As I am using UIWebView, need detect the clicked link/button/url from the website needs to opened in new tab.

I have tried following questions, but none of these working as expected. Everything is opening in the same WebView.
[UIWebView detect when javascript is loading a new page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9403810/4228638)
[Opening popup links in UIWebView, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1245224/4228638)

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: `but none of these working fine` : What is the error you are facing ?

Comment: Modified question. Everything is opening in the same WebView. :(

Answer (score 1):

May use `UIWebView`'s delegate to detect events

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: I am always getting "NavigationTypeOthers". only. :(